# Creating single ENUM and using it in multiple tables in PostgreSQL using Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, enums, sequelize.js

I am new to PostgreSQL and Sequelize and I am trying to create a single ENUM type and using it at multiple different tables in PostgreSQL. But so far I am not able to do so, I have tried the `table_name.getAttributes().column_name.values` command to get the values of an existing ENUM and using it in other table, but this has created a new ENUM type with same values.

What should I do to achieve the desired functionality ?

Also I am using this code -

```
    column_name: {
       type: Datatypes.ENUM('value1', 'value2')
    }
```

to make an ENUM type, but this is creating a new column in the table, can I do something so that I could create an ENUM type without creating a new column ?

Answer (score 1):

temporary solution: Create the enum manually first through a query, and set the type to the name of the enum:
type: `my_enum_name`,

In the migration, you can add

```
await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
  `CREATE TYPE my_enum_name AS ENUM ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');`
);
```

before defining the table.

then in table you can use type as **my_enum_name**

```
await queryInterface.createTable('tableName', {
fieldName: {
  type: 'my_enum_name',
},
```

});